# possible mongo architecture for SaaS

Tags: mongodb, saas

I'm creating a platform where customers (users) are from different organisations. So I would like to keep their data totally separated according to organisations they belong. How would you suggest to store such data in mongo db? On which level?

Comment: And what's the size of data for one organisation (mean and max)?

Answer (score 3):

Are you keeping the data separate for security reasons (i.e. compliance or regulation) or simply for administration/ease-of-use?

If it's the former, I'd go with separate databases at the very least, if not separate MongoDB instances. Separate instances enables you to perform segregation at an IP level through something like `iptables` so that you can tie down different instances to different IP ranges, representing the different organisations presuming they will be accessing the data.

If it's the latter, I'd still go with separate databases because it gives you the ability [to have different users on a database level](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication) and from [version 2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/), concurrency will be [on a database level](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4328) (so there's no sharing of the write lock, for example, that you'd have if you split it out on collection level).

As a FYI, here's some additional information on schema design in MongoDB -

- [Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design)
- [Schema Design Presentation by Kyle Banker](http://www.slideshare.net/kbanker/mongodb-schema-design)
- [Schema Design Blogs from Customers](http://blog.10gen.com/post/23237721457/blogging-contest-mongodb-schema-design)
- [MongoSF2012: mongodb-schema-design-insights-and-tradeoffs](https://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf-2012/mongodb-schema-design-insights-and-tradeoffs)
- There was actually a [schema introduction webinar held last week](https://www.10gen.com/events/webinar/intro-to-schema-design) that you can now listen to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a document for each organization and put the user's details into sub-documents inside the root document.

If the overall users' profiles are so big that don't fit into MongoDB document size (16 mg), then you can use different approach by creating a document for every user and add a field referring to the organization.